# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fs' before initialization

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I try to use fs on a discordjs bot (v13) but I have a strange error.

I have literally 3 lines between the moment when I can console.log my fs object and the error :

> ```
> // Get FS
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> // Recieves commands
> client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
>     console.log(fs); // OK
>     switch(interaction.commandName) {
>         // Get list of all maps for this server
>         case 'maps':
>             const pngfiles = fs.readdirSync('./maps/').filter(f => f.endsWith(".png")); // NOT OK !!!!!!!
>             response = "**List all maps available in this server:**\n\n\n"+pngfiles.join("\n")+"\n";
>             break;
>     }
> });
> ```

And the error :

```
/home/chenille33/DPW/app.js:156
                const pngfiles = fs.readdirSync('./maps/').filter(f => f.endsWith(".png"));
                                 ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fs' before initialization
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/chenille33/DPW/app.js:156:34)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:74:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/chenille33/DPW/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1137:20)

Node.js v18.0.0
```

What I've missed ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was not passing `"fs"` as string inside `require`.

Just changing to `const fs = require("fs");` worked.

**Screenshot of error:**

[image]

Answer (score 14):

That specific error implies that somewhere else in your function scope (not shown in the code in your question), you likely have `const fs = ...` or `let fs = ...` and are thus attempting to redefine `fs` in this function scope which is hiding the higher scoped `fs`.

The error means that you're trying to use the variable `fs` BEFORE its `const fs = ...` or `let fs = ...` definition in this scope have been executed.  Unlike with `var` (where definitions are internally hoisted), you can't use a variable before its declaration with `let` or `const`.

Based on the bit of code we can see, I would guess you're doing this in one of the other `case` handlers in your `switch` statement or somewhere else in the function containing this `switch` statement.  When you don't use braces to define a new scope for each `case` handler, then those are ALL within the same scope and all `const` or `let` definitions there can interfere with each other.

So, look for a redefinition of `fs` somewhere else in this function.  And, if that isn't obvious to you, then post all the code for this function where the error occurs.

---

Here's a stand-alone example that reproduces that exact same error.  This is the kind of thing you should be looking for:

```
let greeting = "hi";
const fs = require('fs');

switch (greeting) {
    case "hi":
        fs.readFileSync("temp.js");
        console.log("got hi");
        break;
    case "goodbye":
        const fs = require('fs');       // this redefinition causes the error
                                        // when the "hi" case executes
        console.log("got goodbye");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("didn't match");
        break;
}

// or a redefinition of fs here (in the same function) would also cause the error
```

When you run this, it gives this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fs' before initialization
```

Or, similarly, if you were defining `fs` somewhere else in the same function containing the `switch` statement, but after the `switch` statement.  That would also cause the same problem.

Comment: In fact, it was after this code I have another `cont fs = required('fs');`.... Thank you :)

Comment: @Chenille33 - This is a good example of how you really should declare your imports at the top of your module (at module scope and module initialization time), not within your function.  And, when you go to ESM modules (the future of the language), you will be forced to do these types of static imports all at the top of the module anyway.  Anyway, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had a variable called `const process = null` causing the node.js process to be overridden.

So I simply removed the variable and it worked.